# Getting 404 Error on Second Domain - Magento 2 Multi-Store

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

So I have a LEMP stack set up on a staging server and on my local. I have it set up as a Multi-Store. The staging server and local are identical. Except that the local is running off of Laravel Valet and the Staging server is just a regular LEMP stack.

I have the Multi-Store setup, on my local it works perfectly. For the secondary domain it shows me exactly what I should expect to see. But on the Staging server I can verify it's loading the secondary site, but I get a 404 error.

The only difference that I can find is that on my local Laravel Valet is running off of /index.php and that is where I had to set the variables to load the secondary site. But on the Staging server I'm running a specific Magento config and it's loading based on /pub/index.php And this is the site that comes up with a 404 error on the secondary domain.

I can't figure this one out. The index.php files are similar but there are a few differences. All I can assume is that slight difference in document root is causing the issue. The ideal configuration I'm sure is that the document root be set to the /pub/ directory, but this is the method that I can't seem to get working. Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I tried to set the staging server to just use / instead of /pub like my local is using. Unfortunately I still got a 404 on the secondary domain, and then on the primary all the assets were missing because of an incorrect path on those elements now.

**UPDATE:** I didn't have a home page created but it stilled showed on local. I created one anyway, still doesn't work. Oddly enough all other URL's work. Try to go to a category page, it works. Try to go to the login page, it works. The only thing that I think doesn't work is the home page that I've found so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured the problem.

I never set the default Home Page under:

**Stores >> Settings >> Configuration >> General >> Web >> Default Pages**

Now granted it was automatically picking up the default but the default was ear marked as only available for the other website not for all stores. And I did create a new page ear marked for the second website, but I didn't know that it also had to be set here as the default page. Silly mistakes, but I hope someone can learn from me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough for comments.

Check the .htaccess file and clear the cache and reindex everything.

Comment: This is using Nginx so no .htaccess file. I've cleared the cache, reindexed everything, rebuilt all the static directories, everything I can imagine. Again this works fine on local. And the primary domain works fine, but the secondary domain throws a 404 error, doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Check the nginx requests (access.log and error.log) see where exactly it goes the request.

Check the DB core_config_data file and make sure you're base url has a slash at the end.

Comment: There is a slash at the end of the base URL. I looked at the log file and it just says "GET / HTTP/2.0" 404. It seems to me like it's not loading the index.php at all when it's default. However, for all sub pages it does, and for the primary store in this multi-store setup it does and they both are sharing the same config as just aliases. It's a head scratcher.